# Does the weather affect my Smurfs?

Tags: smurfs-village

I noticed that although it is mostly sunny in my Smurf village, sometimes it is raining.

Does that actually affect anything (crop growth, etc), or is it purely cosmetic?

Comment: Well when it's raining they smurf, and when it's sunny they smurf.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure rain doesn't affect any major things in-game. It might cause smurfs to go inside, but that's it.